# FORM VALIDATION PHP BOOTSTRAP VSCODE

Tags: php, vscode, bootstrap-5

quisiera su ayuda en poder resolver este asunto del uso del FORM VALIDATION, usando ajax, estoy usando el codigo de validacion.

Aqui el codigo me reconoce los errores dentro de los input si esta vacio, pero cuando mando el formulario rellenado, todos los datos se van por el URL, aun asi en el controlador  print_r($_POST)"

```
const frmRuoli = document.querySelector('#frmRuoli');
const cod_ruolo = document.querySelector('#cod_ruolo');
const nameruolo = document.querySelector('#nameruolo');
const statoruolo = document.querySelector('#statoruolo');
const descruolo = document.querySelector('#descruolo');
//Elementos para mostrar errores
const error_cod_ruolo = document.querySelector('#error_cod_ruolo');
const error_nameruolo = document.querySelector('#error_nameruolo');
const error_statoruolo = document.querySelector('#error_statoruolo');
const error_descruolo = document.querySelector('#error_descruolo');
frmRuoli.addEventListener('submit', validar);
function validar(e) {
if (frmRuoli.checkValidity() == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (cod_ruolo.value == '') {
        error_cod_ruolo.textContent = 'Il codice è obbligatorio';
    } else if (nameruolo.value == '') {
        error_nameruolo.textContent = 'Il nome del ruolo è obbligatorio';
    } else if (statoruolo.value == '') {
        error_statoruolo.textContent = 'Seleziona uno stato obbligatorio';
    } else if (descruolo.value == '') {
        error_descruolo.textContent = 'La descrizione è obbligatorio';
    } else {
        const url = base_url + 'Rol/Registro';
        const data = new FormData(this);
        const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('POST', url, true);
        http.send(data);
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
}
frmRuoli.classList.add('was-validated')
}
```

cuando ejecuto con los campos vacios me salen los errores en los input en rojo y con el mensaje de que el campo esta vacio, pero cuando lleno el formulario y mando me sucede esto se me recarga la pagina y se muestroan todos los datos ingresados en el URL, apesar que en el controlador coloque un print_r($_POST);

```
public function Registro(){
    //if (isset($_POST)){
        print_r($_POST);
}
```

ejemplo del URL:

```
http://localhost/bdapp/Rolcod_ruolo=RU00000002&nameruolo=ewq&statoruolo=1&descruolo=dsa
```

Comment: Hola Abel, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes y agregues tu código como texto, de esta forma evitarás recibir votos negativos, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Hola Marce, gracias por el sugerimiento , la pregunta fue modificada.